# Acer Aspire Timeline - Power control application?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, acer-aspire

I recently purchased an Acer Aspire Timeline 3810TZ notebook. It comes equipped with 2 modes, one for power saving (screen is dimmer, etc) and another for when connected to a power source.

However, I'd like to control the settings for power save mode (specifically to make the screen a bit brighter) but the system didn't seem to ship with an app installed to modify these settings. Browsing the support site proved unsuccessful also.

Anything out there I can do to control the notebook's power save settings?

Edit: Windows 7 Home Premium 64bit

Comment: What operating system (OS)?  XP/Vista/7?

Comment: Sorry, Win7 Home Premium 64bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there something wrong with the [power options](http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/windows-7/features/power-management.aspx) built in to Windows 7?

[image]

You can access it under Control Panel, or open the Start Menu and type "Power".

Comment: Well, I feel like a dummy. My last machine had an app that came from the manufacturer that controlled all the power settings. Didn't realize Win7 had this. Thanks!